# What is the best way to migrate data from one DB2 database to another?

Tags: database, db2, data-migration

I've tried to create backup on one machine and move to another. But I have a problem since I have different OS (Sun-64 and NT-32). Is there another option to move a Db2 database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backups in DB2 do not work to do a migration between some platforms (there is an issue with the endian)

The best way to do your migration (from Sun to Windows) is by using db2move. This tool will create a set of files (one for table) that contains the metadata and the data. With these files, you can import them in other platform by also using db2move and voilà.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002079.html

Comment: You can use a backup to do a migration if they have the same endian, and the architecture is the same or bigger in bits (32 -> 32, or 32 -> 64). For more details, take a look at this page: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0005960.html

Comment: Sun-64 -> NT-32 are definitely not compatible for backup & restore route.